# Function to check the return code of supplied command

Tags: bash

this is a naive attempt to write a command return code checker, as for a long script I have to check `$?` multiple times. So I wrote a function `run_check_proceed()` which run with following syntax:

`run_check_proceed [0|1] <command> #1st arg: to print output or not, 2nd arg: actual command.`

```
run_check_proceed()
{
display_command=0;

#this flag will decide to print the commands output on stdout or not. this is set by first argument to the function.
provided_display_flag=${1};
#check if the flag is either 0 or 1 and store the rest of the arguments into command variable, else exit.
if echo ${provided_display_flag} |grep -qP '^[01]$' ;then
   if [ ${provided_display_flag} -eq 1 ];then
       display_command=1;
   fi
   shift;
   command=$@;
else
    echo "Error: First argument must be either 0/1. 0 : to do silent run, 1: to print the command outputs."
    exit 1;
fi

#run the command
return_text=$($command 2>&1 )

if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo "[$(date)]:[Error(${BASH_LINENO[0]})]: $command failed $return_text"
    if [ $display_command -eq 1 ];then
        echo "$return_text"
    fi
else
    echo "[$(date)]:[Info(${BASH_LINENO[0]})]:) $command Sucessful"
    if [ $display_command -eq 1 ];then
        echo "$return_text"
    fi
    return 0

fi

}

#sample runs
run_check_proceed 1  cd /home/${USER}
run_check_proceed 1  pwd
run_check_proceed 1  cd /var/log          #this should cd to /var/log
run_check_proceed 1  pwd
```

In the above execution, I am doing cd to my home dir, then issuing pwd, which is showing correct dir, then I am doing cd to /var/log and then doing pwd which is still showing old directory. I sense that this is because I am doing cd from inside the function and its not applicable on parent shell. So , I am 99% sure that this approach of checking return code is not going to work. But for rest 1% I need others view , if there is some tweak which can help me to avoid writing hundreds of `if command; then ... ;fi` blocks.

```
bash   ./run_check.sh
[Tue Apr 30 13:52:35 CDT 2019]:[Info(41)]:) cd /home/monk Sucessful

[Tue Apr 30 13:52:35 CDT 2019]:[Info(42)]:) pwd Sucessful
/home/monk/temp
[Tue Apr 30 13:52:35 CDT 2019]:[Info(43)]:) cd /var/log Sucessful

[Tue Apr 30 13:52:35 CDT 2019]:[Info(44)]:) pwd Sucessful
/home/monk/temp
```

Comment: You are running `$command` in a subshell; there's no way to change the working directory of the *current* shell that way.

Comment: ^ In addition this is generally bad practice as it can get confusing.  Simply use the full directory for any commands you have such as `ls -lah /var/log` instead of `cd /var/log; ls -lah`  --  **PLUS** it's almost always better to use the pre-set-up variable that (most times) is already gtg for you -- `$PWD`

Comment: If you're just trying to fail on the first command that returns a non-zero exit, you might want to "set -e" at the top of your script https://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/

Comment: I am using `cd` and `ls` as example only

Comment: [Don't use `set -e`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Also, see [this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for information about putting commands in variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead: redirect output into a file.

```
run_check_proceed() {
    local OPTARG OPTIND opt
    local display=false
    while getopts :d opt; do
        case $opt in 
            d) display=true ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))
    local file=$(mktemp)

    #run the command
    "$@" >"$file" 2>&1
    local exit_status=$?

    local status=Info result=Successful
    ((exit_status != 0)) && { status=Error; result=Failed; }

    printf '[%s]:[%s(%d)]: "%s" %s\n' "$(date)" "$status" "${BASH_LINENO[0]}" "$*" "$result"
    $display && cat "$file"

    rm "$file"
    return $exit_status
}

#sample runs
run_check_proceed     date                                  # verify no output
run_check_proceed -d  sh -c 'echo oops >&2; exit 42'        # verify Error output
run_check_proceed     cd
run_check_proceed -d  pwd
run_check_proceed     cd /var/log          #this should cd to /var/log
run_check_proceed -d  pwd
```

which outputs

```
[Tue Apr 30 16:54:41 EDT 2019]:[Info(27)]: "date" Successful
[Tue Apr 30 16:54:41 EDT 2019]:[Error(28)]: "sh -c echo oops >&2; exit 42" Failed
oops
[Tue Apr 30 16:54:41 EDT 2019]:[Info(29)]: "cd" Successful
[Tue Apr 30 16:54:41 EDT 2019]:[Info(30)]: "pwd" Successful
/home/jackman
[Tue Apr 30 16:54:41 EDT 2019]:[Info(31)]: "cd /var/log" Successful
[Tue Apr 30 16:54:41 EDT 2019]:[Info(32)]: "pwd" Successful
/var/log
```

Comment: thank you @glenn  for this wonderful answer. this could save lot of lines of code just to check return code.

Comment: one note, variable assignment `let x=10` is working whereas `x=10` does not.

Comment: another note `run_check_proceed -d  my_dir=${HOME}` does not work , any suggestion ?

Comment: To get arbitrary shell [simple commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) working, you'll need to use `eval`, but then the quoting gets harder. Try `eval "$(printf "%q " "$@")" >"$file" 2>&1`