# Execute and store the result in Shell Script

Tags: shell

I have generated multiple statements via for loop those statements has to be executed and store each result in a variable using shell script

for example :

```
ls
ls -l /abc
ls -l /def
```

Output : 1 is success and 0 is failure

```
Command1:0
Command2:1
Command3:0
```

Comment: ...wait, you want the *exit status*, not the *result*? Where do these commands come from? Are they in an array? Are they in subsequent lines of a script?

Comment: you can check a general answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927187/function-to-check-the-return-code-of-supplied-command

Comment: `store_result() { declare -g -a results; local retval; "$@"; retval=$?; results+=( "$retval" ); return "$retval"; }` -- thereafter, `store_result ls; store_result ls -l /abc; store_result ls -l /def` and your `results` array will have the desired values.

Comment: Is there anyway which we can add via simple awk statement

Comment: I have multiple commands which executes one after another like two statements are running independently like for example result1 : abc result2:0 result3:def result4:1 then expected output has to be abc : 0 and in next line def : 1